# Google Analytics 4 x Flutter change/ override device category

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am now setting up analytics on my mobile flutter app and I would like to see the different device types that are being used by my users.

The device types I have configured within flutter are Mobile, Mobile Large, Tablet and Tablet Large.

However google analytics only see's one device category for all these device types (mobile) as seen in the photo:

[image: Mobile device category tile in google analytics 4]

My question really is... how would I override this value to show the device types that I use/ refer in flutter. I have tried to use the following function:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.instance
    .setUserProperty(name: "device_type", value: "my device type here eg. mobile large");
```

However this does not change the device category within google analytics 4, but can be seen as a user property in debug view.

[image: Image of google analytics 4 debug view capturing user property device_type]

All events etc are appearing as intended.

I hope this makes sense, I am still learning google analytics 4, appreciate any help and advise with this. Thanks